# List items not correctly aligning with an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, html, css

I have a simple `ng-repeat` `<li>`. Each `<li>` consumes 33.33% of the width so 3 items per row.

However, for some reason the items in the second row do not line up. After a big of digging, if i apply a `min-width` of say, `400px`, then it works. But, i can not do this as the description text length is dynamic.

HTML:

```
<ul class="grid-wrap">
  <li class="grid-col one-third" ng-repeat="job in Jobs" ng-init="descriptionLimit = 20">
    <div>{{ job.JobTitle }}</div>
    <div>{{ job.Location }}</div>
    <div>{{ job.JobDescription | limitTo:descriptionLimit }} 
      <span ng-click="descriptionLimit = job.JobDescription.length"> >> </span></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul, ol {


list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.grid-wrap {    
    margin-left: -3em; /* the same as your gutter */
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
}

.grid-col {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 3em; /* this is your gutter between columns */
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}

.one-third {
    width: 33.33%;
}
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/oWXrqoJpaYPDbe4TwT3c?p=preview

If you click on the `>>` the description will expand and you can see each `<li>` does not line up:

[image]

Comment: In what way do they not line up? The result in the plunker looks fine to me. So what am I supposed to be looking for?

Comment: The only thing I can see is that the columns have different texts, so at certain widths, the second column wraps more than the third one: "Sustitute Math Teacher (Fixed Contract)" wraps to two lines while "History Teacher" does not.

Comment: @MrLister - Please see the attached image for the alignment issue i am seeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might something like this be what you are looking for?

```
.one-third:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
  clear: both;
}
```

I.e. if you want to have exactly a maximum of 3 `li`s per row, and you want to always align your rows vertically, you'll need to explicitly do so.

*Edit:* And of course you could do this also with Angular, for example like this, first define a clearing class:

```
.clear-li {
  clear:both
}
```

and then apply it with `ng-class`:

```
      <li class="grid-col one-third" ng-repeat="job in Jobs" ng-init="descriptionLimit = 20" ng-class="{'clear-li': ($index % 3 === 0)}">
```